# Проблемы с пропорциональным изменением картинки в div

Tags: html, css

Необходимо организовать блоки фиксированного размера, в которых будут еще по 2 блока, с картинкой и подписью. Картинки могут быть любых размеров и нужно ограничить их по высоте и расположить картинку по центру блока.

```
<div class ="gc">
    <div class ="ic">
        <img class ="gi" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/128/home-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Основная проблема заключается в том, что нельзя использовать max-height и max-width, т.к браузер этого не понимает.

Для лучшего понимая пример с max-height и max-width.

http://jsfiddle.net/j2tku1rz/15/

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  background: #f00;
  width: 256px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.block-image {
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid #606060;
  height: 256px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block-image>img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-image">
    <img class="gi" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_960_720.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    Simple text Simple text Simple text Simple text Simple text Simple text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-image">
    <img class="gi" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/128/home-icon.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    Simple text Simple text Simple text Simple text Simple text Simple text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-image">
    <img class="gi" src="https://www.spacex.com/files/assets/img/20090110_vertical002.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
    Simple text Simple text Simple text Simple text Simple text Simple text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы блоки были фиксированного размера, следует использовать width/height.
Чтобы элементы внутри блока были по центру, используй text-align, он применяется не к самому элементу, а к внутренним.

```css
.gi {
margin-top:25%;
/*но лучше в процентах не задавать, а делать в пикселях
почитай про свойство vertical-align, тоже поможет
*/
}

.ic {
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px double black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 250px;
  background: #fc3;

}
```

```html
<div class="gc">
  <div class="ic">
    <img class="gi" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/128/home-icon.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Решил вопрос следующим образом. Задал размеры контейнера с изображением, а самому изображению установил высоту равную 100%, центровку изображения сделал, установкой text-align: center; для gc.

```
.gc {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 265px;
    width: 212px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.ic {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    height: 202px;
    width: 202px;
}

.gi {
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.gn {
    position: absolute;
    height: 48px;
    width: 202px;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```